# Single click to submit form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm having an issue when trying to submit my form. I have made a workaround so that the input gets sent to parse.com by using a hidden button which is visible until all fields are filled in, then this button is hidden and the real submit button is enabled. The problem is that I want to be able to submit the form directly by clicking the submit button without having to click the button twice. I have the following HTML:

```
<form id="vcardForm" method="post" >
    <p>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="text" id="vorname" name="vorname" required />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="text" id="email1" name="email1"  required />
        <label id="atteken" >@</label>
        <input type="text" id="email2" name="email2 "  required />
        <textarea  id="fullemail" name="fullemail"></textarea>
            <p>
        <input type="text" id="telefon" name="telefon" onclick="getFullemail()"     />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="text" id="firma" name="firma" required />
    </p>
    <p>
       <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" onclick="functions()" value=" " disabled>
       <button type="button" id="submitKnop" onclick="validateForm()" ></button>
```

Javascript:

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
            function getFullemail() {
                document.getElementById('fullemail').value =
                        document.getElementById('email1').value + '@' +
                        document.getElementById('email2').value;
            }

</script>

<script>
function validateForm() {
var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
var vorname = document.getElementById('vorname').value;
var email = document.getElementById('fullemail').value;
var firma = document.getElementById('firma').value;
var telefon = document.getElementById('telefon').value;
if(name == '' || vorname == '' || email == '' || firma == '' || telefon == '' ) {

alert('Bitte alle Felder ausfüllen. Danke.');
e.preventDefault();
}else {
document.getElementById('submitKnop').style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById('submitBtn').disabled = false;
}
}
</script>
<script>
    function functions() {
        sendTheMail();

    }
</script>
```

Parse.com script

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var parseAPPID = "bla";
    var parseJSID = "bla";

    Parse.initialize(parseAPPID, parseJSID);
    var VcardObject = Parse.Object.extend("VcardObject");

    $("#vcardForm").on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log("Handling the submit");
        //add error handling here
        //gather the form data

        var data = {};
        data.name = $("#name").val();
        data.vorname = $("#vorname").val();
        data.fullemail = $("#fullemail").val();
        data.telefon = $("#telefon").val();
        data.firma = $("#firma").val();

        var vcard = new VcardObject();
        vcard.save(data, {
            success:function() {
            openPage('danke');
                console.log("Success");
            },
            error:function(e) {
                console.dir(e);
            }
        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It will spare your from using two buttons.When submit button is clicked check if all the fields are filled in or not.Use `&& operator` instead of `|| operator.`Because you want all the fields to be filled

```
if(name != '' && vorname != '' &&  email != '' &&  firma != '' && telefon != '' )
```

If all fields are filled it will  alert a message which will tell you that your  form is submitted.Otherwise it will alert you to fill all the fields

```js
function validateForm() {
var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
var vorname = document.getElementById('vorname').value;
var email = document.getElementById('fullemail').value;
var firma = document.getElementById('firma').value;
var telefon = document.getElementById('telefon').value;
if(name != '' && vorname != '' &&  email != '' &&  firma != '' && telefon != '' ) {

alert('form is sumbitted.');
e.preventDefault();
}else {
 alert('fill all fields !!');
}
}
```

```html
<form id="vcardForm" method="post" >
    <p>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="text" id="vorname" name="vorname" required />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="text" id="email1" name="email1"  required />
        <label id="atteken" >@</label>
        <input type="text" id="email2" name="email2 "  required />
        <textarea  id="fullemail" name="fullemail"></textarea>
            <p>
        <input type="text" id="telefon" name="telefon" onclick="getFullemail()"     />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="text" id="firma" name="firma" required />
    </p>
    <p>
       <input type="submit" id="submitBtn"  onclick="validateForm()" value=" submit " >
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include it in the code, in my full html-page this function is defined, so that isn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you'd like to click button after form is filed and if all fields are valid the form should be send. If so you need to do following changes:
1) remove from html

```
<input type="submit" id="submitBtn" onclick="functions()" value=" " disabled>
```

2) change your validateForm - replace this lines

```
document.getElementById('submitKnop').style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById('submitBtn').disabled = false;
```

with

```
functions()
```

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't work because the script which sends it to parse.com (the sendTheMail() just sends some text to the given emailadress) is activated with  $("#vcardForm").on("submit", function(e) so the submitBtn can't be deleted.

Comment: Well, there is no telepathist. If you dont show code of sendTheMail i dont know what exactly it do.
Form sending has no relation with presence of submit button, you can use form.submit() even if there is no submit element in form

Comment: I've added the parse.com script

Comment: and how all this connected with   sendTheMail?
when this piece of code
    function functions() {
    sendTheMail()
    }
should be called?

Comment: The sendTheMail should be called together with the parse script when the form is filled in completely and the user clicks the submit button. If the user clicks the submit button when one or more fields are empty, they should get an alert and the form should not be submitted.  The sendTheMail sends some text to the given emailadress using Mandrill.

Comment: well, if so the simpliest way that i can see is modify your paste.com script and call validateForm and sendTheMail from it. See my answer below for details

Answer (score 0):

modify validateForm

```
function validateForm() {
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var vorname = document.getElementById('vorname').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('fullemail').value;
    var firma = document.getElementById('firma').value;
    var telefon = document.getElementById('telefon').value;
    if(name == '' || vorname == '' || email == '' || firma == '' || telefon == '' ) {
        alert('Bitte alle Felder ausfüllen. Danke.');
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

and replace

```
    console.log("Handling the submit");
    //add error handling here
    //gather the form data
```

with

```
if(!validateForm()) return
sendTheMail(...al your params here)
```

and the last step replace in your html

```
<input type="submit" id="submitBtn" onclick="functions()" value=" " disabled>
<button type="button" id="submitKnop" onclick="validateForm()" ></button>
```

with

```
<input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value=" ">
```